# How to run Manipulate variable with different ranges?

Tags: functions, function-construction, manipulate

In this code my `c` variable runs from `-5` to `5`.

 What should I do if I want to run only in some ranges like `-3<c<-1&& 2<c<4`? 
How can I do that?

```
Manipulate[
 Dynamic@Show[
   MapThread[
    ReplaceAll[
       p_Point :> {p, 
         Text[Style[#4, 20], Offset[{5, 5}, p[[1]]], {0, -1}]}]@
      Normal@Plot[#, {x, -5, 5}, Mesh -> {{#5}}, 
        MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.03], #2], 
        GridLines -> {Range[-5, 5, 1], Range[-5, 5, 1]}, 
        ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, 
        PlotLegends -> 
         LineLegend["AllExpressions", 
          LabelStyle -> 
           Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Blue, 20, Bold], 
          LegendMarkers -> 
           Graphics[{Thickness[0.5], 
             Line[{{-20, 0}, {20, 0}}]}]]] &, {{Sin[x], x^2 - 3}, 
     ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, 
     ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, {1, 2}, {c, 1/c}}]], {c, -5, 5, 0.1}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What should I do if I want to run only in some ranges like -3<c<-1&&
> 2<c<4?

You can do the following. Set the range as you wanted it.

```
Manipulate[c,
 {{c, -2, "c"}, Range[-3, -1, 0.1]~Join~Range[2, 4, 0.1], 
  Appearance -> "Labeled", ControlType -> Slider}
 , TrackedSymbols :> {c}
 ]
```

And now

[image]

Comment: thanks, if I have a general expression such as `(c <= 0 || c >= 1) && -5 <= c <= 5` would it be possible to convert to `Range[-5, 0, 0.1]~Join~Range[1, 5, 0.1]` using some code?

Comment: I just did this `Select[Range[-5, 5, 0.1], (# <= 0 || # >= 1) &]`

Comment: I do not understand `(c <= 0 || c >= 1)`  slider needs an actual finite interval. Does not handle open ended interval.   What is the actual interval you want the slider to move over if it is different that in your question?  You can't just say for c < 0.   Need to tell it from where to start and where to end.

Comment: But if what you tried with the `Select` command worked for you, that is great. May be I am not understanding your comment above or what you are trying to do. Because you can just do `Range[-5, 5, 0.1]`  and you get same thing.  You could always use `Join` to build any set of intervals together.

Comment: In addition `(c <= 0 || c >= 1)`, there is also `-5 <= c <= 5` so it's closed ended invterval.

Comment: How can I make it run automatically as in my initial code not slider to drag like above?

Comment: Something like this. I only need to press a button then it runs automatically.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Files/IntroductionToManipulate.en/Video_3.mp4

Comment: To have manipulate run automatically, one way is to use [AutorunSequencing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AutorunSequencing.html)

Comment: But why does my original code do that without AutorunSequencing?

Comment: @hana I copied and pasted your code to my notebook V 13 and it does not run on its own. I had to move the slider to make it change. I do not understand what you are saying there I am afraid. I also do not understand why you have `Dynamics` inside `Manipulate`. It is not needed.

Comment: I mean this. 
When I run my code, there is a `+` symbol and if I press it I got this so I can make it autorun.
https://ibb.co/wCkrZR4

Comment: @hana  Yes, this is standard. All sliders have this option if you open them. DO you mean you are not using slider for `c`?  We were talking about slider all the time. Now it changed? I am little confused. May be you can make separate question on this issue then if it is not related to intervals which is what your current question was asking.

Comment: I want to press a button and then it runs as in the image above. I don't want to use mouse and drag as it's inconvinient.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the option `Exclusions` to `Manipulate` control:

```
{c, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> {"Open", "Labeled"}, Exclusions -> Range[-1, 2., .1]}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: That looks good. What if `c` is given by an expression like this (assume that it's closed bouns).  And this expression is not fixed. 
`(c <= 0 || c >= 1) && -5 <= c <= 5 `

Comment: @hana, you can use `Exclusions -> Range[0,1., .1]` for that case. Not that `Exclusions` option only takes a discrete set of values; it does not allow a continuous interval.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. The range for `c` is `(c <= 0 || c >= 1) && -5 <= c <= 5` which you as a human can simplify it to `(-5 <= c <= 0)&&(1<= c<= 5` and the range to remove `0<c<1` and from this we can write `Exclusions -> Range[0,1., .1]` . All of this is easy as a human. But how can I generate `Exclusions -> Range[0,1., .1]` from the given expression above by writing some code to make that as a machine?

Comment: I see. Maybe something like `Range[#, #5, .1] & @@ Reduce[! (c <= 0 || c >= 1) && -5 <= c <= 5]`?

Comment: Yes, it looks easy but why is it `#5`? I tried to evaluate `Reduce[! (c <= 0 || c >= 1) && -5 <= c <= 5]` to `0 < c < 1` first and then `Range[#, #5, .1] & @@(0 < c < 1)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `Range[First@#, Last@#, .1] &` (instead of `Range[#, #5, .1] &`) works in both cases.